# Hide ionic ion-tabs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I follow [this codepen](http://codepen.io/pietromarrone/pen/vGPOWQ?editors=101) to hide ion-tabs :

```
<ion-tabs ng-class="{'tabs-item-hide': hideTabs}">
    // --> my tabs go here
</ion-tabs>


<ion-view hide-tabs>
  // --> my contents
</ion-view>
```

my directives.js

```
.directive('hideTabs', function($rootScope, $ionicTabsDelegate) {   return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $el) {
      $scope.$on("$ionicView.beforeEnter", function () {
        $ionicTabsDelegate.showBar(false);
      });
      $scope.$on("$ionicView.beforeLeave", function () {
        $ionicTabsDelegate.showBar(true);
      });
    }   }; });
```

It works fine, but suppose we have a third level of navigation (after chat-detail.html in Chats tabs), we'll call it chat-detail-more.html. If we use back button to go back to chat-detail.html, tabs bar comes back
Any idea to hide tabs bar in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "hidden" attribute of ion-tab like this -

```
 <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive "> 
        <ion-tab hidden="{{condition}}" title="Home" icon-off="ion-ios-home-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-home" href="#/tab/chats">
   </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab hidden="{{condition}}" title="Log-in" icon-off="ion-person-stalker" icon-on="ion-person-stalker" href="#/tab/login">
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Using this we can show/hide tab.